# Python nan with complex arrays

Tags: python, numpy, nan, complex-numbers

Inserting a `nan` in Python into a complex numpy array gives some (for me) unexpected behavior:

```
a = np.array([5+6*1j])
print a
array([5.+6.j])

a[0] = np.nan
print a
array([nan+0.j])
```

I expected Python to write `nan+nanj.` For analyses it often might not matter, since `np.isnan` of any complex with either real and/or imaginary parts is True. However, I did not know the behavior and when plotting the real and imaginary parts of my array it gave me the impression I had info on the imaginary (however there is none). A workaround is to write `a[0] = np.nan + np.nan*1j`. Can somebody explain the reason for this behavior to me?

Comment: Related link: Surprising behaviour of NaN with complex numbers #12919 (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12919)

Comment: I completely agree with both answers below, but I regard the zero imaginary part as an undesirable side effect, especially since as suggested in the link above Python should raise some kind of warning.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you create an array with complex values:

```
a = np.array([5+6*1j])
```

You've created an array of `dtype` complex:

```
a.dtype
# dtype('complex128')
```

So by adding a value which only contains real part, it will be converted to a complex value, and you will thus be inserting a number with a complex component equal to `0j`, so:

```
np.complex(np.nan)
# (nan+0j)
```

Which explains the behaviour:

```
a[0] = np.array([np.nan])
print(a)    
# [nan+0.j]
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably hast to do with numpy representation of nan:

> NumPy uses the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point for Arithmetic
>   (IEEE 754). This means that Not a Number is not equivalent to
>   infinity.

Essentially `np.nan` is a `float`. By setting `x[0] = np.nan` you are setting its value to a "real" float (but not changing the `dtype` of the array, which remains complex), so the imaginary part remains untouched as `0j`.

That also explains why you can change the imaginary part by doing `np.nan * 0j`